# Meaning of "God's fool"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I am a great and sublime fool. But then I am God's fool, and all His works must be contemplated with respect.
>
> —By Mark Twain

What's the meaning of God's fool??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a common expression, though it may have been more common in the past.

It merely means "A fool created by God", with the implication "I may be a fool, but even this fool is created by almighty God", or "I may be a fool, but so is everybody compared to the wisdom of God".

It might allude to 1 Corinthians 3:19: "For the wisdom of this world is foolishness with God."

But it's not a familiar expression to me.

Comment: I was once part of a conversation about not liking magpies (because they may prey on the young of other garden birds). An old gentleman said "Well, they're God's birds." I took him to mean 'They are a part of the natural world and have as much right to live as any other species'.

Comment: I upvoted. Mark is familiar with self-mockery. There, he first calls himself a fool and then says that it's is god's fault.